# select option is updating state but wont render the correct name of the current state as option

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a CustomInput from reactstrap that is not showing the correct state.name when clicked. I am passing a stringifiedJSON object as value on the option, then The handle change is parsing the string back into an object. I can console.log(state) and see the object just fine.
If I set the onChange to  `onChange={({target}) => setCountry(target.value)}` this renders the selected option correctly, If I select united states, it shows united states, If I select Mexico it shows Mexico so on and so forth.
However, When I set my onChange to `onChange={handleChange}` with handleChange being this below, It will only show the first item in the array, In my case United States. I can select Mexico, the console.log will show the updated state, However the select option looks like United States is still chosen.

```
 const handleChange = async(event) => {
                      setCountry(event.target.value)
                      const obj = JSON.parse(event.target.value)
                      setCountry(obj)
                      
                      
                    }
```

```
<Input
          type="select"
          id="country"
          name="country"
          className="mb-3"
          value={country}
          onChange={({target}) => setCountry(target.value)} <--- this renders correctly
        >
          
          {numberCountries.map((country, index) => ( 
            <Fragment> 
              <option key={index} value={JSON.stringify(country)}>{country?.name}</option>
            </Fragment>
          ))}
```

```
<Input
          type="select"
          id="country"
          name="country"
          className="mb-3"
          value={country}
          onChange={handleChange} <--- this calls update state and updates correctly but the select option wont render the correct country.name. 
        >
          
          {numberCountries.map((country, index) => ( 
            <Fragment> 
              <option key={index} value={JSON.stringify(country)}>{country?.name}</option>
            </Fragment>
          ))}
       
        </Input>
```

Here is the numberCountries thats being mapped over for the options

```
 [
{
    name: 'United States',
    countryCode: 'US',
    areaCodes: AreaCodes,
    type: {
      local: {
        amount: '400'
      },
      toll_free: { 
        amount: '400'
      },
    }
  },
  {
  name: 'Australia',
  countryCode: 'AU',
  type: {
    local: {
      amount: '1500'
    },
  }
},
{
    name: 'Belgium',
    countryCode: 'BE',
    type: {
      local: {
        price: '410'
      },
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: What is the `typeof country` your passing as the `value` prop to the `Input` component?

Comment: I added it just now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of converting the whole country object to a string, you should use the `countryCode` property as its value.

Its not advised to use the index of an array as the key, so if you can use the `countryCode` as its key aswell.

```
<Input
    type="select"
    id="country"
    name="country"
    className="mb-3"
    value={country.countryCode}
    onChange={handleChange}
>
    {numberCountries.map(({ countryCode, name }) => (
        <Fragment> 
            <option key={countryCode} value={countryCode}>{name}</option>
        </Fragment>
    ))}
</Input>
```

And then your `handleChange` function should be

```
const handleChange = async (event) => {
    const obj = numberCountries.find(country => country.countryCode === event.target.value);
    setCountry(obj);
};
```

Comment: This solution worked for me. How did you get to where you think this way? Any particular courses or reading you recommend?

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. I only started React recently but I've been using JS a while. I only used the tutorial React provided on their website and haven't looked into other places. But I would just say you should try to find the simplest and shortest possible way to solve the problem.

Comment: If you're stuck again and you need help. Tag me here and I'll respond as soon I can. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `setCountry(obj)` in the `handleChange`

Comment: I need the stringified json to be parsed back into an object though so I can check if country.type exists and then render another input only if the country.type exists.

Comment: You should use `JSON.parse` only when you check. Not update back into an object

Comment: So how would I parse the updated state before checking to render this component? ``` {country?.type && ( 
          <Fragment>
        <span className="fs-1">Choose Number Type</span>
        <div className="mb-2"></div>```

Comment: Before return use `const  countryObject = JSON.parse(event.target.value)`

Comment: `countryObject?.type && ...`